# Unable to load map fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a PigLatin code that generates an object A with the following schema:

```
pages: {timestamp: datetime,url: chararray,source_url: chararray,status_code: chararray,http_headers: map[],content: chararray}
```

I then store it using (with the `-schema` option):

```
STORE pages INTO 'pages' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
```

When I load it back (from another script), I see the description properly:

```
pages = LOAD 'data/layers/raw_content';
DESCRIBE pages;
> pages: {timestamp: datetime,url: chararray,source_url: chararray,status_code: chararray,http_headers: map[],content: chararray}
```

But when I run the following statement, it fails:

```
A = FOREACH pages GENERATE http_headers#'content-type';
DUMP A;

2014-07-13 14:49:44,398 [Thread-14] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0004
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing     [POMapLookUp (Name: POMapLookUp[bytearray] - scope-33 Operator Key: scope-33) children: null     at [null[26,39]]]: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.util.Map
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:338)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:282)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.util.Map
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POMapLookUp.getNext(POMapLookUp.java:99)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POMapLookUp.getNextDataByteArray(POMapLookUp.java:116)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:313)
... 9 more
```

Full error log is here: http://pastebin.com/BLzsciU8

**If I don't load `pages` but instead copy the script that generates it everything works.**

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: The name of your value is `content` not `content-type`

Comment: @GoBrewers14 - Thanks but `content` is another field in the tuple. I have problems querying `http_headers` which is a map that contains the key `content-type`.  Anyway - I agree it's confusing, let's think of another key in the map, like `accept`